# NumberFormatExceprion for binary string

Tags: java, parseint, binary-string

I'm trying to get int from String "11010001110011000000000111111110" with code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt("11010001110011000000000111111110", 2);
```

but i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11010001110011000000000111111110"
```

Comment: Since the number is only 32 bits you can use `parseUnsignedInt`, but you will get a negative number.

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks @david-conrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply because the value represented by the string with binary content is too large for an **int** data type. You need to parse to **long** data type. The binary string represents a value of **3519807998**. Integer maximum value (Integer.MAX_VALUE) is: **2147483647**. Try this:

```
String binaryString = "11010001110011000000000111111110";
long n = Long.parseLong(binaryString, 2);
```

Or this way:

```
String binaryString = "11010001110011000000000111111110";
long lng = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2).longValue();
System.out.println(lng);
```